# Securing Kafka REST API endpoints

Tags: nginx, http-authentication, kafka

We plan to use Kafka for publishing updates to our customers. The plan is to use the dedicated topic for each client. To makes things simpler for them we want to utilize REST API.  So that **user1** will be able to get updates from `/api/topic1` and won't be able to get updates from `/api/topic2` (URLs are just for reference).

However, at the moment REST API [does not have](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest/issues/160) any authentication/authorization out of the box.

I am wondering whether we can achieve our goal by 3rd party tools (like nginx)? By placing some proxy in front of REST API or whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference purposes there are few options to walk through:

1. [ngx_http_auth_request_module](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth) - [blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-authenticate-users/)
2. If you are on AWS - [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/)
3. [OpenIG](https://forgerock.org/openig/) standalone reverse proxy, main purpose is actually authentication.
4. Not sure how utilize it, but Azure App Services also have external authentication
5. [WSO2 API Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Basic+Auth)

If I would prioritize how I investigate this topic, I would probably start from provider specific solutions, then nginx module, then OpenIG, then WSO2 offering.